# Same origin & destination, but different time => no coverage. Why? How can I fix this? (HERE Transit API v8 )

Tags: api, maps, here-api, heremaps, transport

I've been working on a project which utilises the HERE Transit API v8.
Unfortunately, **for some reason, the API seems to return the following error.** The strange thing is, I've tried the same exact API call (same destination, same origin) but only changed the arrival_time by like 10 minutes and it suddenly started/stopped working.

```
{'notices': 
[
{'title': 'Routing is not possible due to missing stations in a given range', 'code': 'noStationsFound'}, 
{'title': 'Route between origin and destination is not possible given current input parameters', 'code': 'noRouteFound'}, 
{'title': 'This notice is deprecated, see noRouteFound', 'code': 'noRoutesFound'}
], 
'routes': []}
```

To give an example, **the following worked:**

```
origin: 49.1922443,16.6113382
destination: 50.0777015686,19.7847995758
arrivalTime: 2022-09-10T06:00:00.000Z
```

But **the following didn't work:**

```
origin: 49.1922443,16.6113382
destination: 50.0777015686,19.7847995758
arrivalTime: 2022-09-10T06:10:00.000Z
```

Comment: Hi ,Could you please provide whole request including detail option?

Comment: Hi , I believe there is no public transit for arrival time from 2022-09-10T06:10:00.000 to 2022-09-10T07:00:00.000Z to get the destination.

Answer (score 0):

As told by Park, there is no public transit for arrival time from 2022-09-10T06:10:00.000 to 2022-09-10T07:00:00.000Z to get the destination